# Use Spring layout For Hand GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, springlayout

I have a jframe that has a lable and two radiobuttons.

I use spring layout, But my second radioButton seen in top left of page!

```
public class tester extends JFrame {

public tester() {
    add(create());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel create() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("Yes");
    JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("No");
    group.add(r1);
    group.add(r2);
    JLabel lable = new JLabel("Today is sunday?");
    panel.add(lable);
//        panel.add(group);      // How add this?

    panel.add(r1);
    panel.add(r2);

    JButton savebt= new JButton("Save");
    JButton cancelbt=new JButton("Cancell");
    panel.add(savebt);
    panel.add(cancelbt);

    panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 1, 3, 50, 100, 25, 50);
    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new tester();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now this exception occur:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 5
```

I want to display my two buttons on below of radio button's line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three items in your panel, so the number of columns should be 3:

```
SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 1, 3, 50, 100, 25, 50);
```

> //        panel.add(group);      // How add this?

You don't need this.  ButtonGroups don't get added to a panel.  They are for button selection management and are not displayed.

Comment: Good help, But now i add two button's that should be in below of that line, and should be adjacent.

Comment: @Sajjad- 2 rows and 3 columns = 6 cells.  You are adding only 5 components though.  You can't have empty cells in your grid.  If you do it will throw this exception.  Add an empty JLabel in the last cell.